# python code error not detected in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code to code in python. I have the Microsoft python extension. I am having trouble with basic bug detection. For example, I import a class that does not exist from a file because of a typo and that does not get detected at all.
For example:

```
from my_functions import MFunction
```

while the name of the class is actually `MyFunction` (y is missing in the call)
does not give signal an error in the UI at all and only throws an error at the run.

Is there another extension I need to install or some sort of config I haven't configured correctly?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Python extension, Pylance and Python for VSCode, and it's working great for me.

Comment: Do you have the directory open?

Comment: @Pavindu there are 30M+ users happy with `ms-python`, what is the added value of your comment, it is not working OK for Courvoisier

Comment: @Courvoisier I cannot reproduce the problem. Have you tried reinstalling "Python" extension.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Yes, directory is open. I have a workspace with 2 projects, but I dont think it matters. same issue with only one project.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code you have to consider your current working directory (CWD) plus the files and methods you want to import.

For example:
If you open vscode in the folder of your project and open a terminal or start the python file with the ui "play" button, vscode might not set your cwd in the right folder for the "import"-command to find the package/function. The "import" command checks for your current PATH and if your folder is not in there it might not find the .py file and its containing functions to import it as a package (by the way yes the imported function needs to be imported exactly as it is defined in the .py file so in your case the 'y' in MyFunction needs to be there in the "from my_functions import MyFunction").
Check the execution path in the terminal and if it is not set to project folder you have to "change directory" (cd) into your project folder. This will cause your python execution to run from your project folder and therefor find the .py file with its functions.

Another option would be to copying your .py file you want to import into the side-packages folder of your python installation.

Usualy starting once from a valid path should correct the display of imported packages in vscode.
Also you might consider using a virutal env which basicly installs a local python version plus side-packages folder into your project folder. But you do have to activate that venv before executing the .py file.

Comment: I have a virtual environment. I always do.  The path in the terminals for both of my projects (I have 2 in the workspace) point to its correct project. and they are each under their own .venv

Comment: wait am i understanding right? You have 2 Projects with seperate venv in your workspace in vscode? i can imagine that this constellation can cause the problem.

I would suggest trying to copy the imported .py file directly into the folder of the calling .py file, open this folder as cwd directly, run it and if this works you might have a issue with your vscode run-path configuration (maybe vscode doesn't know which venv to execute) . Also a reminder just in case: mixing .venvs is not possible . So i think to execute each .py file in their respective venvs simultaniously will not work.

Comment: update: I am not 100% sure, but I think it was cause i have an extension called kite that is causing problems.
as for multiple projects under one workspace: it's very safe. vs code handles it beautifully. you have 1 workspace with separate projects, each has their own venv. It's nicer than having to open 2 vs code.